# Springfox Spring Web MVC endpoint description

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

I'm using Springfox in a Spring Web MVC project, without any of the custom Springfox/Swagger annotations. In Swagger UI (and of course in the JSON that is generated), the description for the endpoints are just the method names.

Is there any way of automatically using the description as it is in the code comment (which is a properly formatted Javadoc styled comment).

Comment: No! ...  have you looked at https://github.com/RobWin/swagger2markup?

Answer (score 0):

In Swagger2Markup you can write descriptions in AsciiDoc and combine the hand-written documentation with your generated documentation.

I plan to integrate https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet into Swagger2Markup.